# writing binary to a file using unsigned short in C with fwrite()

Tags: c, binary, binaryfiles

I'm trying to write 4 `unsigned short int` numbers represented in hex into a binary file.

I keep getting a lot of junk in addition to the numbers I'm writing, and I'm not sure why. I'm assuming that in the translation from `unsigned short int` to binary, there's junk being written into my file.

My function to write into my binary file is:

```c
int write_file  (char* name, unsigned short int array[x] ){

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(name, "wb");
    if(fptr==NULL)
    {
        fclose(fptr);
        return (0);
    }
    unsigned short int code = 0xABCD;
    const void *ptr = &code;
    fwrite(ptr, sizeof(ptr), 1, fptr);

    unsigned short int code2 = 0x0000;
    const void *ptr2 = &code2;
    fwrite(ptr2, sizeof(ptr2), 1, fptr);

    unsigned short int code3 = 0x0001;
    const void *ptr3 = &code3;
    fwrite(ptr3, sizeof(ptr3), 1, fptr);

    unsigned short int code4 = 0x1101;
    const void *ptr4 = &code4;
    fwrite(ptr4, sizeof(ptr4), 1, fptr);

    return (0);
}
```

Ideally the binary file would be interpreted as:

```
ABCD 0000 0001 1101
```

But I'm getting this instead:

```
abcd f250 0190 0000 0000 eeb6 1915 7ffd
0001 eea6 1915 7ffd 1101 ee96 1915 7ffd
```

Comment: Please note that unsigned short int is guaranteed to be 16bit length minimum; but it is implementation dependence. Please use byte precision to create your binary file;

Comment: Or, just use a data type that is guaranteed to be 16 bits regardless of implementation, like [`uint16_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) in `<stdint.h>`

Comment: Also, mind the endianness of your binary data! (When I was an undergrad, my school did have both big-endian and little-endian computers, but that might be less of an issue today.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You are passing the wrong byte sizes to `fwrite()`.

You are passing the byte size of each `void*` variable. `sizeof(void*)` is 4 bytes in a 32bit build, and 8 bytes in a 64bit build (`sizeof(void*)` would appear to be returning 8 in your case).  You need to instead pass the byte size of the `unsigned short int` variables (2 bytes) that are being pointed at.

You don't need the `void*` variables at all.  And don't forget error checking:

```c
int write_obj_file  (char* filename, unsigned short int program_bin[ROWS] ){

    FILE *fptr = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        return -1;

    unsigned short int code = 0xABCD;
    if (fwrite(&code, sizeof(code), 1, fptr) < 1) {
        fclose(fptr);
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned short int code2 = 0x0000;
    if (fwrite(&code2, sizeof(code2), 1, fptr) {
        fclose(fptr);
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned short int code3 = 0x0001;
    if (fwrite(&code3, sizeof(code3), 1, fptr) {
        fclose(fptr);
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned short int code4 = 0x1101;
    if (fwrite(&code4, sizeof(code4), 1, fptr) {
        fclose(fptr);
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are quick my friend, very, very quick `:)`

Comment: Really quick; fflush is missing though! :-)

Comment: @choppe `fclose()` will flush the file if it hasn't been flushed yet.

Comment: @RemyLebeau; Thanks

Comment: if fptr is actually NULL, do I need to run fclose on it?

Comment: @GordWait no. If `fopen()` returns NULL, there is nothing to close